# Как получить ссылку на изображение от пользователя в Aiogram, Python?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, возникла некоторая проблема с получение ссылки на изображение, отправленного юзером в чат с телеграм ботом.

Я пробовал делать такую ссылку `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{TOKEN}/photos/file_0.jpg`, однако она открывает окно скачивания фото, а мне нужна ссылка именно на **само изображение**, чтобы при открытии ссылки в браузере был предпросмотр.

Эта url нужна, чтобы передавать её в api для дальнейшей работы.

Answer (score 0):

Дружище, я сам задался этой проблемой увидел твой пост и решил её вот таким способом : код ниже.

То есть для достижения цели тебе нужнен и **телеграм бот и дискорд бот**, работает как часы)

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO)
async def process_photo(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    name_image = f"12345.jpg"

    # получаю объект фотки
    photo = message.photo[-1]

    # скачиваю фото в папку со скриптом
    await photo.download(name_image)

    # использую aiohttp вместо requests так как бот исинхронный, советую забыть тут о requests.
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # через апи дискорда отправляю на канал CHANNEL_ID скачанное фото. вставляю токен от дискорд бота
        async with session.post(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/messages',
                                headers={'Authorization': f'Bot {TOKEN_discord}'},
                                data={'content': 'Фото', 'file': open(name_image, 'rb')}) as response:
            data = await response.json()
            # теперь переменная file_url содержит полноценную ссылку для предпросмотра фотографии, и её принимает любое API
            file_url = data['attachments'][0]['url']

    # отправляем ссылку загруженной фотографии
    await message.reply(f"{file_url}")
```